# jqplot zoom - happens only if zoomed till the borders

Tags: javascript, cursor, zooming, jqplot

I am facing an issue with zooming using jqPlots.

I have a graph with multiple y-axes. I have the following lines of code for performing the zoom:

```
cursor: {
            showVerticalLine: true,
            //showTooltip: true,
            followMouse: true,
            showTooltipDataPosition: true,
            tooltipFormatString: '%s x:%s, y:%s',
            zoom: true,
            constrainOutsideZoom: false,
            clickReset: true
        }
```

I am able to zoom with the above. However, the zoom happens only when I drag the zoom area to one of the borders. If I try to zoom somewhere within the canvas, it does not zoom.

Can someone tell me where I could be going wrong?

Thanks, 
S.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem. In fact, the problem is that when you zoom inside the canvas the browser considers the click inside the canvas and execute the function clickReset. When your mouse finish outside the canvas it consider the click outside and doesn't execute the function. I tried on IE9 and it works because it doesn't consider the click during the zoom.

I think that this is a bug in the Jqplot library.

I searched for many hours and I didn't solve the problem. I hope that someone has a solution.

Comment: Hey Karl, pretty true.. I tried removing the clickReset option from the specifications and that worked without any problem. It would reset the zoom upon double click automatically. I too am guessing that there is a bug in the jqplot library. Let's hope someone confirms that.